# Defer state update / rerender in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I created a React component that sends a GraphQL query to the backend to retrieve an image as a base64-encoded string and display it when it's loaded. Until then, it displays a little loading spinner. The code looks more or less like this and works as expected:

```js
const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(...)
const showImage = !loading && !error && data?.image?.base64
const showError = !loading && (error || !showImage)

return (
    <div>
        {loading && <img src={`/loading.gif`} />}
        {showError && <img src={`/error.png`} />}
        {showImage && <img src={`data:image/jpg;base64, ${data.image.base64}`}/>}
    </div>
)
```

But on top of that, the control also allows some basic image manipulation (e.g. a button that tints the image purple), which I implemented with `useState`. Essentially:

```js
const [ purple, setPurple ] = useState(false)

const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(/* pass `purple` to backend */)
const showImage = !loading && !error && data?.image?.base64
const showError = !loading && (error || !showImage)

return (
    <div>
        {loading && <img src={`/loading.gif`} />}
        {showError && <img src={`/error.png`} />}
        {showImage && <img src={`data:image/jpg;base64, ${data.image.base64}`}/>}
        <input type={`checkbox`} onChange={_ => setPurple(!purple)} />
    </div>
)
```

All of that works fine, too, *except* as soon as the checkbox is clicked, the old image disappears and I get the `loading.gif` until the new image is fetched. That's not unexpected but undesired. I'd much rather keep the old image around and set the new image once it arrives.

I experimented with writing the old image's base64 string to a `useState` hook and read it from there until it's replaced by the new image. That works, but I got the impression that the performance was not great. (There are many, many of these components on the site and when the user scrolls long enough, hundreds of them may be loaded, which leads to a bloated React state. Can that be a problem or did I imagine it? Can I profile this?)

Which brings me to my question: Is there a way in React to somehow defer the full rerender and keep the old state around for a while until the new state goes into effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what you are looking, assuming you are using Apollo Client, is `previousData` hook result property

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#previousdata

As per documentation

> An object containing the result from the most recent previous
> execution of this query.
>
> This value is undefined if this is the query's first execution.

So something like (by using `image` variable together with `?.` (optional chaining) you can avoid the boolean variable to decide if to show the image)

```
const { data, loading, error, previousData } = useQuery(/* ... */);
const image = data?.image?.base64 || previousData?.image?.base64;
```

Note: I suggest you to change the loading logic to display the loading spinner only if it's loading and no `image` is set, to avoid both loading spinner and previous image displaying together. You can eventually hide the image if case of errors.

Comment: I was really hoping for a simple solution like that. Very cool, thank you! For the reload, I ended up showing the spinner on the slightly dimmed and blurred previous image.